# Geometry question, triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Alice chose a point $P_0$ on the side $AB$ of triangle $ABC$. Bob drew a circle centered at $B$ through $P_0$, which intersected side $BC$ in $P_1$. Then she drew a circle through $P_1$ centered at $C$ that intersected side $CA$ at $P_2$, then a circle centered at $A$ through $P_2$ which intersected side $AB$ at $P_3$. But Bob did not stop here – she drew another circle centered at $B$, this time going through $P_3$ to get $P_4$ on $BC$.
>
> She continued in the same way, and all her points $P_0, P_1, P_2, \dots$  were on the sides. After a few more steps she noticed a pattern.
> What is this pattern? How would you explain it?

I have found the pattern ($P_6$ becomes $P_0$), but I cannot explain it!

[image: triangle pic]

Comment: Let the sides of the triangle be $a$, $b$, $c$ (with $a$ opposite $A$, etc). Define $r:=BP_0$ as the radius of the first circle about $B$ through $P_0$. What is the radius of the circle about $C$ through $P_1$? and the radius of the circle about $A$ through $P_2$? etc.

Comment: Ok @Blue, thanks for the message, but I'm not familiar with the terms you are using like $:=$ . would you mind putting an answer...?

Comment: "$p:=q$" simply means "define $p$ to be equal to $q$"; so, I'm just assigning $r$ to be the length of $BP_0$. ... Anyway ... You've already discovered the pattern; I think you can figure out the explanation. (Just calculate the radius of each circle until something wonderful happens.) Then write your own answer so that we can upvote your success. :)

Comment: okay I will try :P

Comment: @Blue my answer is finished :) I hope its okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your tips, here's my answer:

> The pattern is that for any point along AB, the line goes back to the starting point.
>
> [image: pic]
>
> Explanation:
>
> I will first define some values.
>
> *a* is the line opposite *A* (BC), *b* is the line opposite *B* (AC) and *c* is the line opposite *C* (AB).
>
> $r_$ is the first radius from *B* to $P_{0_0}$.
> So:
> $s_0=c-r_0$
> $t_0=b-s_0=b-c+r_0$
> $u_0=a-t_0=a-b+c-r_0$
> $v_0=c-u_0=c-a+b-c+r_0=-a+b+r_0$
> $w_0=b-v_0=b+a-b-r_0=a-r_0$
> Now I will do the next point:
>
> $x_0=a-w_0=r_0$
>
> Since the seventh radius is indeed the first, I can confirm that the line always goes back to the starting point.

Comment: @Blue thank you so much for your very kind comment! I really appreciate your advice on the style of diagrams, I will remember them next time I make a diagram. 
BTW I saw your t-shirts designs and they are so cool ;)

Comment: I was so taken by your argument that I completely overlooked a fatal flaw. You defined $w_0$ as the radius of the circle needed to take $P_{0_5}$ to $P_{0_1}$ ... but you don't *know* that a circle can do that. (That's the whole point of the proof!) Thus, you don't *know* that $r_0+w_0=c$, which means you can't make the double-perimeter argument. Bummer. ... I'll mix to my previous suggestion with your work: If your first radius is $r$, then your second radius, $s$, is equal to $a-r$; but then your third radius, $t$, is $b-s$, which is $b-(a-r)=b-a+r$. What happens when you keep going?

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the t-shirts. I haven't promoted them much, so my visit-counter is pretty-much a flat line at zero. I was wondering why it jumped all the way to $1$ today. Mystery solved! :D

Comment: okay @Blue , thank you for spotting my error! I will solve this tomorrow :)